# Update a JQuery progressbar using WCF Duplex callbacks?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, css, wcf

I have a fairly straightforward WCF duplex service hosted on IIS (.NET 4.x)

One particular service method is long running (1-3 minutes), and when this method is triggered by the client, **I would like to provide visual feedback to the user via a JQuery progressbar on the page that updates based on an integer value passed during multiple callbacks.**

I am open to moving away from a duplex implementation, but it seemed like the logical approach at the time...

What is the best way to go about this, keeping in mind that I would like to minimize overhead, and also avoid introducing more technologies like silverlight (though I realize this is a perfectly viable solution for this problem).

Specifically, some code examples might be helpful. Also note that I am new to both JQuery and WCF.

*I wasn't sure what other information to offer to make this question more clear, so if you require more information, please ask and I will amend the original question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not feasible using standard WCF without moving to Silverlight as you would need to use a polling duplex channel at the browser.

There was [an AJAX implementation of the client side of the PollingDuplex protocol done some time ago](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/08/ajax-client-for-http-polling-duplex-wcf.html), which would allow you to have your client progress bar update in response to progress updates from the server (sort of - it still needs the client to poll). Not sure if it works with the latest version of PollingDuplex.